# CSS, I want 3 divs of different heights and widths side by side and level at the top. How do I do this

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend

First off, I know its a stretch that someone is really gonna completely solve this issue for me but even just pointing me in the right direction for what I need to learn to be able to do this is much appreciated. I'm a noob at CSS.

I want 3 divs of different heights and widths side by side and level at the top.

This is my html (its in react but I dont think that should affect how to do this. ClassName is class)

'''

```
  <div className="AppMain">
    <div className="SectionOne" />
      <FishPole fishPoleImg={props.state.fishPoleImg} />
      <FishButton handleClick={props.handleClick}/>
      <FishCount fps={props.state.fps} fishCount={props.state.fishCount} />
      <BaitShop />
    <div />

    <div className="SectionTwo">
     <Structures />
    </div>

    <div className="SectionThree">
      <StructureStore fishCount={props.state.fishCount}/>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I want the 3 divs under `className="AppMain"` to be side by side. SectionOne div will have a width of 270px,SectionTwo div to take up all all of the width that isn't taken up by the other two sections, and SectionThree div will have a width of 300px.

this is what i'm getting right now.  (as you can see I cant even get them side by side, also this picture is very zoomed out so you can see everything)

[image]

Comment: I recommend using [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: Probably just make `.appmain` a flexbox container with `display: flex; flex-direction: row` (of columns, FBL default). Dunno what React thinks of that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing your CSS code would be nice so we can help more, but possibly just adding `vertical-align: top;` to your elements CSS that you at the top would work.

Comment: `Vertical align` only works for graphical elements like `<img>`

Comment: Hey, I was actually able to use flex to solve the problem. Turns out I do know how to use flex I was just organizing the HTML wrong in react.